# Swap Attribute in each item in a list c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list with items as follows:

```
public class Student {
      public string Name;
      public string Nickname;
}

var students = new List<Student> { new Student {Name = "Becca", Nickname = "Rebecca"},
                                   new Student {Name = "Ray", Nickname = "Raymond"}}
```

If I want to swap `Name` and `Nickname` so that `students` would now be

```
var students = new List<Student> { new Student {Name = "Rebecca", Nickname = "Becca"},
                                   new Student {Name = "Raymond", Nickname = "Ray"}}
```

How do I do that in linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever we ask how to do *X* with each item in a list, the answer is usually two things: How to do *X*, and how to do something with each item in a list. Once we see that, we can separate the two problems and start with how to do *X*. The second part, how to do anything with each item in a list, is much simpler.

In this case, how do we do *X* - create a new `Student` from an existing one, with the names swapped?

That could be a method like this:

```
Student SwapNames(Student student)
{
    return new Student {Name = student.Nickname, Nickname = student.Name};
}
```

or simplified as

```
Student SwapNames(Student student) =>
     new Student {Name = student.Nickname, Nickname = student.Name};
```

Having solved that, determining how to do it to to items in a list is easier.

```
var swappedStudents = new List<Student>();
foreach(var student in originalStudents)
{
    swappedStudents.Add(SwapNames(student));
}
```

Or, using LINQ:

```
var swappedStudents = originalStudents.Select(student => SwapNames(student));
```

...or simplified:

```
var swappedStudents = originalStudents.Select(SwapNames);
```

These both produce an `IEnumerable<Student>`. If we wanted a `List<Student>` we could append:

```
var swappedStudents = originalStudents.Select(SwapNames).ToList();
```

In the examples so far, the method that does *X* - in this case, swapping the names, is in a separate function. That can be helpful for readability. But we can also do it inline with an anonymous function, like this:

```
var swappedStudents = originalStudents.Select(
    student => new Student { Name = student.Nickname, Nickname = student.Name });
```

That's an anonymous function that takes a `Student` as an argument and returns a new `Student` with the names swapped.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq's Select method to create a new instance of student with the values swapped.

```
var students = new List<Student> 
{
    new Student {Name = "Becca", Nickname = "Rebecca"},
    new Student {Name = "Ray", Nickname = "Raymond"}
}

var swapped = students.Select(x => new Student {Name = x.Nickname, Nickname = x.Name});
```

Comment: What if there's additional attributes in the `Student` model? if we create a new instance of Student inside `Select`, then the additional attributes' values will be gone, right? Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @superninja LINQ isn't great at doing changes to the state of existing elements, it's primarily for querying. You can declare the new `Student` object and just pass all the previous values for your unaffected fields/properties, or you can just swap the two values in-place within a foreach.